# Is the 'time'-component of 4-force always zero?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, vectors

The 4-velocity of a particle is defined as
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
u_\sigma = \frac{d x_\sigma}{d\tau} = \left(\frac{dx_1}{d\tau}, \frac{dx_2}{d\tau},\frac{dx_3}{d\tau},c\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right),
\end{equation}
where $d\tau$ is the proper time interval. Since
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
dt = \frac{d\tau}{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}},
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
u_\sigma = \frac{d x_\sigma}{d\tau} = \left(\frac{dx_1}{d\tau}, \frac{dx_2}{d\tau},\frac{dx_3}{d\tau},\frac{c}{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}}\right).
\end{equation}
The 4-momentum is defined as $p_\sigma = mu_\sigma$, where $m$ is the [invariant mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum) of the particle. Thus,
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
p_\sigma = \left(m\frac{dx_1}{d\tau}, m\frac{dx_2}{d\tau}, m\frac{dx_3}{d\tau}, \frac{mc}{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}}\right).
\end{equation}
If we now define
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
f_\sigma = \frac{dp_\sigma}{d\tau}
\end{equation}
then the 4-th component of $f_\sigma$ will always be zero because
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
\frac{mc}{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}}
\end{equation}
is a constant. Is this conclusion correct? It doesn't seem to be, yet I am unable to argue against it.

A few observations:

- I am able to define proper time of particle only because it is in an inertial frame of reference. That is, it is travelling with a uniform velocity. Therefore, not just the 4-th component, but all components will be zero.
- If this is correct, is it even possible to write the analogue of Newton's second law in special theory or relativity?

I consulted a few questions asked before, for example [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/379441/physical-significance-of-the-zeroth-component-of-4-velocity-and-4-force) one and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274345/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-the-zeroth-component-of-the-minkowski-force-4-ve?rq=1) one. But I was unable to get a clear understanding of 4-force. Could someone kindly point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean? If velocity is changing, why would the derivative be zero? You are talking about acceleration (4 forces)?

Comment: $\beta$ is not constant if $v$ varies.... As soon as there is spatial acceleration you should also have a temporal componente of $f$.

Comment: There is no such thing as a $4$-vector with the $0$-th component always equal to zero. Lorentz transformations will change it into one with a nonzero $0$-th component.

Comment: The acceleration is that of an object accelerated in one of the frames of reference in uniform relative motion with respect to another (it is therefore not the frames of reference which are in accelerated motion!!).

Comment: we know that:$\;\;a^{\nu}a_{\nu}=-\gamma ^{6}{\vec{a}^{2}-(\vec{\beta}\times\vec{a})^{2}}$
. Now imagine an object with a uniformly accelerated relative motion equation (constant acceleration) in our own frame of reference. If we assume our fixed frame of reference, we have:$\vec{u}=\vec{0}\;\rightarrow \vec{\beta}=\vec{0}\;\;$
since then : $a^{\nu}a_{\nu}=-\vec{a}_{0}^{2}\;,$if the accelerated motion is only along one component:$\;\;\gamma^{3}\frac{dv}{dt}=a_{0}=\frac{d\gamma v}{dt}$

Answer (score 3):

$\gamma mc$ is not a constant. It is a function of $\tau$.

Remember that the gamma factor depends on $v$. It is only a constant when $v$ is constant. For non-straight line paths, gamma can vary in general

> I am able to define proper time of particle only because it is in an inertial frame of reference. That is, it is travelling with a uniform velocity. Therefore, not just the 4-th component, but all components will be zero.

This is false. In general, proper time, along any worldline, is:

$$\int \sqrt{g_{\mu \nu} \frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda} \frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\lambda}} d\lambda$$

$\lambda$ is some labeling parameter of the worldline.

In inertial frames, the metric $g$ is the Minkowski metric. So the proper time of any worldline will be calculated using the distance formula $dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2$.

If you choose $\lambda =t$ in the formula, and use the Minkowski metric, you get:

$$\tau=\int \sqrt {1-v^2(t) }dt$$

Or $$d \tau= \sqrt{1-v^2(t) } dt$$

Comment: That's the point. If the velocity is changing, can I even use Lorentz transformation?

Comment: @Ghoster yeah, but the time component really is zero in that case. I meant to say "can vary in general"

Comment: @AmeyJoshi You can think of non straight line motions in terms of infinitesimal pieces of straight lines glued together. The rule $dt=\gamma d\tau$ still applies for small pieces of the path. Special relativity is not fundamentally about Lorentz transformations.

Comment: @RyderRude, thanks. If we build on this point, how should I write equations (3), (4) and (5)? Would you mind including them in your answer? Perhaps you cannot write them as a comment.

Comment: @AmeyJoshi your equations are correct. Maybe explicitly write $\beta$ as $\beta (t) $ to avoid the conclusion that it is a constant. I've edited the general definition of proper time

Comment: @RyderRude I see your point. But does it mean that if I stick to special relativity, I cannot write an equivalent of Newton's 2nd law? $\beta$ is a constant in special relativity. Is special relativity restricted to the description of uniformly moving bodies?

Comment: @AmeyJoshi $\beta=|v(t) |$ depends on time $t$ in special relativity. Special relativity can describe forces and accelerating bodies. The Lorentz force law is  $\frac{dp^{\mu}}{d\tau}=qF^{\mu \nu} v_{\nu}$. $F$ is the eelctromagnetic field tensor

Comment: @AmeyJoshi special relativity is not restricted to uniformly moving bodies. It is restricted to flat spacetime (ie scenarios without tidal gravity)

Comment: @Dale thanks, your comment is indeed helpful. I was wrong in my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The zeroth component of 4-momentum is energy, kinetic plus rest-mass energy. If a particle increases kinetic energy, the zeroth component changes.

For instance, under a constant proper acceleration in one dimension in relativity (the “relativistic rocket”) the rapidity (which is the linear measure of speed in relativity) should increase constantly with proper time,
$$
\varphi = \alpha~\tau/c.
$$
The $\gamma$ factor in rapidity-speak is given by the hyperbolic cosine $\gamma=\cosh\varphi$ and in its role as time dilation we have $$
\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm d\tau}=\cosh\left({\alpha\tau\over c}\right),\\
t = \frac{c}{\alpha}\sinh\left({\alpha\tau\over c}\right).$$
So then we would find that under this force the zeroth component of momentum will vary with $t$ like,
$$
\gamma~m~c = m~c~\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\alpha t}{c}\right)^2}
$$
and so is obviously not constant.